# How to remove Ubuntu when I installed on wrong hard drive?

Tags: system

I feel this is a stupid question. So basically I have two drives one 120gb ssd and one 1tb hdd. I want to install systems and regular used programs on ssd and put data in HDD. However, i messed up by installing on hdd. How do I transfer the system to the ssd? Or how do I remove the installation on hdd? By the way, the version I installed is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 2):

You don't. If there is nothing to save from the ssd/hdd just reinstall. Install on the ssd should take a mere 15 minutes anyways.

During installation: format the hdd and mount it to a mount point. Create a / with the whole 120Gb --or-- a roughly 30Gb-ish and remainder for /home/. Keep your personal files outside /home and on the hdd so when you need to reinstall you can assume contents on / are safe to delete.